# Postgresql date difference in table and on web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, format

I have weird situation with my PostgreSQL db date value.

On my web site I have calendar for selecting a date and when I select some future date like `"2018-09-23"`  in PostgreSQL table column it is saved as `"2018-09-22 22:00:00"`?

Obviously I am missing something. On web site all the time it shows okay time `"2018-09-23"` but at the table it is  minus one day as you see above.  Why?

[image: Rails console params value sent to server]

[image: Web site calendar selected value]

[image: DB saved value with one day minus ROW 2 (id 82)]

Comment: What time zone is your development machine in?

Comment: (GMT+2)  Europe .. .. .. ..

Comment: Issue may be anyone of the following:

1) Front End Timezone and Machine(Back End) Timezone may vary.

2) Check the parameter value(date field) is set to Value sent from Front End or set to Time.now.

It will be helpful if you share code snippet.

Comment: Postgres use UTC to store datetimes, but your Web App uses GMT+2. This means every hour saved as GMT+2 will be stored in Postgres as UTC, hence the -2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails stores DateTime fields in UTC, but without marking their time zone as UTC. This corresponds to the `timestamp without time zone` type in postgres. So if your time zone is +2, it'll store the time as UTC (+0).

In Rails, `Time.zone` will return the current local timezone (you can add logic to change this by user, for example). When persisting a datetime, Rails will automatically convert the current Time.zone to UTC. However, it doesn't use the Postgres type that actually includes the time zone data, so it relies on convention to convert back and forth to the user's time zone.

If you really only care about the date, use the date type in your migration instead of Timestamp or DateTime.

Times and dates have a lot of subtle quirks and the "right" behavior depends on your use case. In some applications, you need to deal with "local" time when considering date transitions, and sometimes you need to finesse your application or database logic to think in terms of local time and sometimes you care about UTC time.

Comment: you are the man! @Jason I changed field type from timestamp to date and it started to behave correct. Thank you!